# DDD: How to distinguish between application and domain services?

Tags: domain-driven-design, service

I'm exploring Cargo DDD sample.

There is BookingService which belongs to application layer.
But looking at the code, it seems that all methods correspondent to Domain Logic (bookNewCargo, assignCargoToRoute, etc).

[image]

**Why is it in Application Layer then?**

What is the difference between application and domain services?

So confusing!

Comment: You need to re-examine the terms you're using and make sure you fully understand them.  I've never heard of the terms "application layer" and "domain layer,"  and using terms that you don't understand to make decisions about how your code is organized is probably not the best plan.

Comment: See Eric Evans Blue book, page 70.

Comment: In the section titled "Services?"

Comment: In the section titled "Layered Architecutre"

Comment: OK.  Those layers appear to correspond to what I understand to be the Data Access Layer, Service Layer, and Business Logic Layer (more or less).  The short answer to your question is "because that's where the author decided to put it."

Comment: Note that there's no "right" or "wrong" way to write software.  There is Eric Evans' way, Martin Fowler's way, Bob Martin's way, and *the way that best meets your specific requirements.*

Comment: Yes, but there is should be some consistency at least. I see BookingService in the Application layer, and RoutingService in Domain layer, and it is confusing.

Comment: All of the business operations appear to occur in the "Application" layer.  What does the code in the Domain Layer look like?  I suspect you'll find domain objects there, not business transactions.

Answer (score 9):

> Why is it in Application Layer then?

As far as I can tell, because this is an application service -- more specifically, because the *consumer* of this service is the application, not the domain.

For example, take a close look at [BookingService.assignCargoToRoute](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/application/impl/BookingServiceImpl.java#L65), if we strip away the logging and exception handling, we see

```
public void assignCargoToRoute(final Itinerary itinerary, final TrackingId trackingId) {
    final Cargo cargo = cargoRepository.find(trackingId);
    cargo.assignToRoute(itinerary);
    cargoRepository.store(cargo);
}
```

That's a classical pattern for an application to interact with the domain.

1. Obtain a handle to an aggregate root, with a local copy of state
2. Send a command to the aggregate root, allowing it to update the local state
3. Commit the local state change back into the shared repository, so that the changes are visible outside of this particular thread.

[BookingService.bookNewCargo](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/application/impl/BookingServiceImpl.java#L34) is similar; but confused by the fact that (a) creation patterns are *weird* and (b) this particular design is a bit anemic; the domain model, specifically the Cargo aggregate root, should be doing more of the work.

If you work through the call graph, you'll notice that

- [CargoAdminController.register](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/interfaces/booking/web/CargoAdminController.java#L62) invokes
- [BookingServiceFacade.bookNewCargo](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/interfaces/booking/facade/BookingServiceFacade.java#L18) implemented by
- [BookingServiceFacadeImpl.bookNewCargo](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/interfaces/booking/facade/internal/BookingServiceFacadeImpl.java#L49), invokes
- [BookingService.bookNewCargo](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/application/BookingService.java#L23), implemented by
- [BookingServiceImple.bookNewCargo](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/application/impl/BookingServiceImpl.java#L34)

So the consumer of the BookingService is the application (indirectly, the CargoAdminController); this thing isn't a domain service at all.  The domain model never knows it exists.

That's not a great argument by itself.  Another hint that we are dealing with an application service here is that the implementation knows about `Repository`, which is not a domain concept.  Given that domain services are sometimes used to bridge a gap between the rest of the domain model and some application or infrastructure service, we can conclude that heuristic isn't particularly good either.

> How to distinguish between application and domain services?

My advice: don't get caught up in the labels.  Pay attention to cohesion.  Pay attention to what other components change when you change the service.  Watch your dependency graph like a hawk -- if you find your "domain" services getting polluted with application dependencies, that's a hint that you haven't quite gotten the separation of concern properly aligned.

Comment: Repository is a domain concept. Domain layer defines and exposes a repository and/or data access through an interface which is generally implemented in the infrastructure.

Comment: No.  Cargo is a domain concept.  Itinerary is a domain concept.  "Repository" is not - it's a programming concept, not a part of the ubiquitous language of moving cargo.

Comment: It's still the domain layer which exposes the interface. Some tasks are pretty  much unsolvable without access to data layer, such as unique constraint validation. You are given access to data in your domain through the interfaces domain layer defines. And when a business rule that something has to be unique is made it belongs to a place where the rest of the business rules lives as well, the domain layer, not the application layer.

Comment: Sure: but note that aggregates, repositories, and factories are chapter 6 (Life Cycle of a Domain Object), where entities, value objects, and _services_ are chapter 5 (A Model Expressed in Software).

Comment: After some thorough thinking and re-reading several chapters, I need to admit my view on the problem was not entirely correct. I have thus removed my answer, because yours provides a far better insight.

Comment: A pure Repository (get,add) is a domain concept. UnitOfWork (save, commit) is a programming concept.